# Correct what to catch exchange down in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

As per the tutorial, I use `var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);` to register message on the queue.

But I noticed that if the exchange is deleted, (forcefully using the API), or by stopping rabbit, I don't actually get any notification that something is wrong

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body;
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
};
```

What events can I register to tell if/when the exchange was deleted or if I was somehow disconnected for whatever reason?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong if an *exchange* is deleted. Since your consumer consumes from a *queue*, the only result is that no more messages are routed from this exchange to the queue.

This is different from your *consumer* being disconnected from the queue or the queue being deleted which will result in your consumer being disconnected. Check out [`HandleModelShutdown`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming) and other methods your consumer can implement for such cases.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your answer. I have no issue with the exchange/queue/Rabbit being deleted. My question is, how can I tell if the exchange/queue has been deleted, none of the event fire when the exchange/queue are deleted.